# Custom object attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce

is it possible to create a custom object for attachments master detail to a another custom object.If yes can anyone share VF code and controller code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VF or Apex to create custom objects and define relationship.
There is step by step process for doing that. Follow these links -

http://rainforce.walkme.com/how-to-create-a-custom-object-in-salesforce/
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/01/how-to-create-master-detail.html

Comment: thnks for the suggestion ...here object dosent mean a custom obj with notes and attachment related list...a custom object which acts like notes and attachment to be precise...i can create a custom obj..but i have to achieve the second part thats the actual query here